# Ember: jQuery Post with nested JSON-Payload

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, post, ember.js

I want to POST some JSON to my REST-Server.

The JSON looks like that:

```
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "socials": {
      "facebook": {
        "uid": "1234321",
        "fbsrCookie": "sdfsdfhgsd"
      }
    }
  }
```

The POST-Call in Ember looks like that:

```
Ember.$.post('http://localhost:3000/register', data).then(function ...
```

Inspecting the Message with the Developer-Tools of Firefox show me that the parameters are the following

```
name: "John Doe"
socials[facebook][uid]: "1234321"
socials[facebook][fbsrCookie]: "sdfsdfhgsd"
```

Because of the Header "Content-Type" which is *"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"* I cant handle with the values as objects on my node.js-backend (since its not JSON).

Is there a way a to read the properties from the server-(node.js)-backend? Or how can I send the payload as JSON?

Comment: What Node HTTP framework are you using? Express should handle form encoded requests so long as you include its [`bodyParser` middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body), for example.

Comment: @sdgluck Im using express, indeed. Well if Im trying to read the request like: `console.log(req.body.socials.facebook.uid);` nothing will be printed.

Comment: What if you log `req.body` only?

Comment: @sdgluck please see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, like @sdgluck mentioned, the express.js-Framework (which Im using) can also parse the form-data (url-encoded)parameters decribed in my question above. So I double checked the including of the bodyParser-middleware of express.js and changed the "extended"-Parameter to true like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

Now express.js also parse the parameters and let me access them via dot-notation (like so: `req.body.socials.facebook.uid`).

Thanks to @sdgluck !

Answer (score 2):

If you have a REST server that's returning json then send it `application/json`:

```
vara data = {
  "name": "John Doe",
  "socials": {
    "facebook": {
      "uid": "1234321",
      "fbsrCookie": "sdfsdfhgsd"
    }
  }
}

Ember.$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```